# Any relationship between the Three Guṇas (गुण) and the three Ayurvedic Doshas ( दोषः)?

Tags: scripture, dharma, gunas, ayurveda

In Hinduism (*Sanātan Dharma*)  the number - "three",.occurs in many instances

The *Trimurtis* - Brahmā, Vishnu and Mahesh (त्रिमूर्ति - ब्रह्मा, विष्णु और महेश ), the Three (*Guṇas*) Qualities - Sattva, Rajas, Tamas (त्रि-गुण - सत्त्व, रजस, तमस) , the Three Major *Lokas* (त्रिलोक), in the *Ayurveda* (आयुर्वेद) too, there are three fundamental bodily bio-elements - *Vatta, Pitta, Kapha* (त्रिदोषोपदेशः - वात, पित्त, कफ).
The three threads that together constitutes the *janeu* - *the upanayana thread.*

So my question being, is there anything mentioned about the importance or significance of number "three (3)" in any of the Vedic Scriptures?

More importantly, does any Scriptures or School of Thought talks about any kind of relationship between the Three Qualities (त्रिगुण) & *Trimurtis* in terms of the three *Ayurvedic Doshas* ( दोषः) and/or the three threads of the *janeu*?

Comment: Emphasizing the idea of three: 'pranav' or 'Tara' or 'Omkar' or simply 'om' composed of the 'Aaa-kar', 'U-kar' and the ' Ma-kar with an ardha-matra'!

Comment: I think you're stretching it with any 'fascination' with the number three. There are innumerable examples of other numbers. The development of the Ayurvedic system is heavily dependent on Hindu scriptures and philosophy. You may like to read Prof. Dasgupta's 'A History of Indian Philosophy', especially Vol 2, Chapter XIII. It deals with the development of the Indian medical schools and their ties to Indian philosophical thought. Available here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism

Comment: The word Om(ॐ) or A U M means Br(A)hma, Vishn(U) and (M)ahesh and represents the beginning, middle and end of existence and is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabda_Brahman of formless Brahman, and written with base form ३ in Sanskrit & 3 in english, a PIE language.Similarly, Vata, Pita and Kapha are controlled by three main spinal nerves within body called Ida, Pingla and Sushmana. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadi_(yoga). Left feminine Tamsik Ida(lunar) controls kapha(phlegm), Right masculine Rajsik Pingla(solar) controls Pitta(heat) and central Sushmana Satvik controls Vata(Air/Prana)